# Make search "blocks" in textfield , like pinterest seach android

Tags: java, android, search, pinterest

I wanna add search box or whatever it's called in my android app , like this :
 [enter link description here](http://www.brianhonigman.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Screen-Shot-2014-12-16-at-2.35.30-PM-compressor-1024x513.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the colored boxes with the X's in them, those are called chips, and [there are a few libraries that offer them](http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=chips).